# Convenient representation for matrix equation through rvec/devec operator and kronecker

Tags: calculus, matrices, kronecker-product

I have matrix equation in the form $y = Ax$, where $y=\begin{pmatrix}
y'_1 \\ 
y'_2 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
y'_M \\
y''_1 \\ 
y''_2 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
y''_M
\end{pmatrix}; $$ and, $$ x = \begin{pmatrix}
x'_1 \\ 
x'_2 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
x'_N \\
x''_1 \\ 
x''_2 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
x''_N
\end{pmatrix}$ and $A$ is block diagonal matrix with the block size MxN.

Is there a way to obtain equivalent representation where
$y=\begin{pmatrix}
y'_1 & y''_1 \\ 
y'_2 & y''_2 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots \\ 
y'_M & y''_M\\
\end{pmatrix} 
$

and $x = \begin{pmatrix}
x'_1 & x''_1 \\  
x'_2 & x''_2 \\  
\vdots & \vdots \\  
x'_N & x''_N \\
\end{pmatrix}$

With a suitable transformation on $A$?

I've seen the operator that transform the "x" vector in that way is a type of generalized rvec or devec (reverse vec operator). And they are intimately related with Kronecker and tensor product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original matrix can be written as block matrix
$$
A =\left(
\begin{matrix}
C & D \\
E & F
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Then
$$
A x = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
C & D \\
E & F
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x'\\
x''
\end{matrix}
\right)
=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
y'\\
y''
\end{matrix}
\right)
= y
$$
so
$$
(C \, D) x = y' \\
(E \, F) x = y''
$$
We are looking for $B$ with
$$
B (x' \, x'') = (y' \, y'')
$$
This seems possible for the special case $D = E = 0$ and $B = C = F$.